# Using JScrollPane inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I currently try to implement a JScrollPane in my program but I just can't get it to work.

I used the Eclipse WindowBuilder to setup my GUI, which looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30898.png).

In the currently shown TabbedPane you can see three TextAreas acting as headlines at the top and a bunch of TextAreas at the bottom. The entries at the bottom are generated dynamically and I want to allow the user to add, remove and modify those items there. Therefore the user should be able to scroll through these entries at the bottom.

As you can see by the ScrollBar at the right side of the program, I already tried to implement a JScrollPane, but without any success of actually being able to scroll. I tried a lot of different stuff already, using multiple types of containers, read all the explanations and watched all the tutorials I could find, but I just can't seem to be able to implement it into my own particular case here.

In line #61 I create the JPanel which holds my Items in Form of my self created Class ItemPane.
In line #64 I then create my JScrollPanel with the JPanel as Viewport in the constructor.
Within the for-loop in #70-#74 I then add the ItemPanes to my JPanel.

As you can see in the picture everything works fine, just that I can't scroll through my Items which extend further to the bottom of my window.

Any suggestion what I'm doing wrong or why it isn't working?
I would really appreciate it!

(Note: I've stripped down the code to everything that could matter. I removed simple Getters and Setters and everything that doesn't have anything to do with the layout itself.)

Here's what the Initializing of my Window looks like:

```
1 public class Test
2 {
3   JFrame frame_Main;
4   JTextField textField_Col1;
5   JTextField textField_Col2;
6   JTextField textField_Col3;
7
8   private void initialize()
9   {
10      frame_Main = new JFrame();
11      frame_Main.setTitle("My Program");
12      frame_Main.setResizable(false);
13      frame_Main.setBounds(100, 100, 1080, 720);
14      frame_Main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
15      frame_Main.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
16
17      JTabbedPane tabbedPane_Main = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
18      tabbedPane_Main.setBorder(null);
19      tabbedPane_Main.setToolTipText("");
20      tabbedPane_Main.setBounds(0, 0, 1074, 691);
21      frame_Main.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane_Main);
22
23      JPanel panel_Tab1 = new JPanel();
24      panel_Tab1.setBorder(null);
25      tabbedPane_Main.addTab("Tab 1", null, panel_Tab1, "");
26      panel_Tab1.setLayout(null);
27
28      JTabbedPane tabbedPane_Tab1 = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
29      tabbedPane_Tab1.setBorder(null);
30      tabbedPane_Tab1.setBounds(0, 0, 1069, 663);
31      panel_Tab1.add(tabbedPane_Tab1);
32
33      JPanel panel_Tab1_1 = new JPanel();
34      panel_Tab1_1.setBorder(null);
35      tabbedPane_Tab1.addTab("Tab 1.1", null, panel_Tab1_1, null);
36      panel_Tab1_1.setLayout(null);
37
38      textField_Col1 = new JTextField();
39      textField_Col1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
40      textField_Col1.setBounds(10, 11, 341, 20);
41      textField_Col1.setEditable(false);
42      textField_Col1.setText("Col 1");
43      panel_Tab1_1.add(textField_Col1);
44
45      textField_Col2 = new JTextField();
46      textField_Col2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
47      textField_Col2.setBounds(362, 11, 341, 20);
48      textField_Col2.setEditable(false);
49      textField_Col2.setText("Col 2");
50      textField_Col2.setColumns(10);
51      panel_Tab1_1.add(textField_Col2);
52
53      textField_Col3 = new JTextField();
54      textField_Col3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
55      textField_Col3.setBounds(713, 11, 341, 20);
56      textField_Col3.setEditable(false);
57      textField_Col3.setText("Col 3");
58      textField_Col3.setColumns(10);
59      panel_Tab1_1.add(textField_Col3);
60
61      JPanel panel_Tab1_1_Items = new JPanel();
62      panel_Tab1_1_Items.setLayout(null);
63
64      JScrollPane scrollPane_Items = new JScrollPane(panel_Tab1_1_Items);
65      scrollPane_Items.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
66      scrollPane_Items.setBounds(0, 42, 1064, 593);
67
68      panel_Tab1_1.add(scrollPane_Items);
69
70      for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
71      {
72          ItemPane temp = new ItemPane(new Item("Col1 " + i, "Col2 " + i, "Col3 " + i), i);
73          panel_Tab1_1_Items.add(temp);
74      }
75
76      JPanel panel_Tab1_2 = new JPanel();
77      panel_Tab1_2.setBorder(null);
78      tabbedPane_Tab1.addTab("Tab 1.2", null, panel_Tab1_2, null);
79      panel_Tab1_2.setLayout(null);
80
81      JPanel panel_Tab2 = new JPanel();
82      panel_Tab2.setBorder(null);
83      tabbedPane_Main.addTab("Tab 2", null, panel_Tab2, "");
84      panel_Tab2.setLayout(null);
85  }
86 }
```

While ItemPane being:

```
1 public class ItemPane extends JPanel
2 {
3   JTextPane[] textPanes;
4
5   public ItemPane(Item item, int num)
6   {
7       super();
8
9       setBounds(10, 11 + num * 30, 1043, 20);
10      setLayout(null);
11
12      textPanes = new JTextPane[3];
13
14      String[] texts = new String[] { item.getCol1(), item.getCol2(), item.getCol3() };
15
16      for (int i = 0; i < textPanes.length; i++)
17      {
18          textPanes[i] = new JTextPane();
19          textPanes[i].setEditable(false);
20          textPanes[i].setBounds(351 * i, 0, 341, 20);
21          textPanes[i].setText(texts[i]);
22          add(textPanes[i]);
23      }
24  }
25 }
```

And Item:

```
1 public class Item
2 {
3   private String m_col1;
4   private String m_col2;
5   private String m_col3;
6
7   public Item(String col1, String col2, String col3)
8   {
9       m_col1 = col1;
10      m_col2 = col2;
11      m_col3 = col3;
12  }
13 }
```

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts.

Comment: Should I avoid using it in general? Should I just avoid using it with JScrollBars?
In either case, why should I avoid it? What problems can it bring?
And as I said, I used the WindowBuilder within Eclipse, which I think puts some Layouts to null by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally managed to accomplish what I wanted to!

Since Arvind just said I should avoid using null layouts, I tried to specify them. So I changed the code at #62 to

```
 panel_Tab1_1_Items.setLayout(new BoxLayout( panel_Tab1_1_Items, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

With only that it didn't work, then I set the preferredsize of my ItemPane. In the class ItemPane (2nd code snippet) I simply added the Code between #23 and #24 like this:

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1043, 20));
```

Now everything is like I wanted it to be and I can finally scroll through all my Items!